# Why instanciating new date return different results in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox

Coping this in Chrome and Firefox returns different results:

```
(new Date(2017, 2, 22, 0, 0, 0)).valueOf()
```

or even this:

```
(new Date(2017, 2, 22)).valueOf()
```

How can I fix this?
I get `1490128200000` in Chrome and `1490124600000` in Firefox.

I'm using Windows and my timezone is +3:30 tehran and daylight saving is on.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @trincot could you check again? I think this is effected by OS environment. I'm using Windows and my timezone is +3:30 tehran and daylight saving is on.

Comment: The results differ by exactly one hour. What is the result of `(new Date()).toISOString()` in both browsers?

Comment: @ImanMohamadi you need to check back your results again - there's no difference in numbers reported either by chrome or firefox here, and I'm using Windows OS. (or check the timezone on both computers in case you are running the test on different computers with different browsers. No other explanation there

Comment: If there is a difference, it must mean both browsers use different locale settings. Use UTC instead, and it should be the same: `Date.UTC(2017, 2, 22, 0, 0, 0)` will always be 1490140800000 in all time zones.

Comment: @trincot look I added some screenshots. Is there anything else I should check? whats your guess?

Comment: Just do `new Date()` on both browsers and see what the output is.

Comment: I am getting the same result in both browsers. @trincot gave a good explanation. For sure, it has something to do with your local settings.

Comment: 00:00 on 22 March, 2017 is when daylight saving starts. Get the time one millisecond later (or earlier) and they'll both show the same value. This is just a different interpretation of when daylight saving starts.